# Problems with setAttribute

Tags: php, dom

In the code below,

```
$item->setAttribute('onclick','target_popupAFB(this)');
```

is giving me a headache, it writes the value target_popupAFB(this) but it does not write the name. the result is  ="target_popupAFB(this)"

I am a newbe using DOM

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($doc);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $item) 
{
    $tempsrc=$item->getAttribute("href");
    if(substr($tempsrc,-4)==".mp3")
    {
        $item->removeAttribute('target');
        $item->setAttribute('target','msp');  
    }   
    $tempta=$item->getAttribute("target");
    if($tempta!=="msp")
    {   
       $item->removeAttribute('target');
       $item->setAttribute('target','_blank');  
     }
    if(substr($tempsrc,-4) ==".jpg" || substr($tempsrc,-4) ==".bmp" || substr($tempsrc,-4) ==".gif" || substr($tempsrc,-4) == ".png")
    {
       $imgA=explode("/",$tempsrc);
       $c=count($imgA);
       if($imgA[1]=="AFBEELDINGEN" && $imgA[0]=="..")
       {        
          $img=end($imgA);      
          $item->setAttribute('href','http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/AFBEELDINGEN/afb.php?img=' .$img);
          $item->setAttribute('onclick','target_popupAFB(this)');         
       }
    }
}
$doc = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: What would you like it to write instead of `this`?

Comment: It had to write:: onclick="target_popupAFB(this)"

Comment: I have to apologize, I made a stupid mistake, it was another function which was causing the problem. setAttribute is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the main things : thinqs to https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute , you haven't to remove attribute and set a new one. setAttribute will overide the attribut if existe.

i thinqs you shoudn't use setAttribut when you want to add event but addEventListener (doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).
Glad it help. gl

Comment: I will have to solve the issue in PHP, addEventListener is a JS method